# Sending array of entities as parameters in Struts2

Tags: java, arrays, struts2, batch-processing

For example I need to save several employees from form:

```
<h4>Employee 1</h4>
<div>
<input type="text" name="names">
<input type="text" name="ages">
<input type="text" name="salaries">
</div>

<h4>Employee 2</h4>
<div>
<input type="text" name="names">
<input type="text" name="ages">
<input type="text" name="salaries">
</div>

<h4>Employee 3</h4>
<div>
<input type="text" name="names">
<input type="text" name="ages">
<input type="text" name="salaries">
</div>
```

for that I do this:

```
public EmployeeAction extends ActionSupport {

  private String[] employeesNames;
  private Integer[] employeesAges;
  private Integer[] employeesSalaries;

  // Setters and getters

  public String save() {
    Employee[] employees = new Employee[size];
    // Creating employee objects with names, ages and salaries
    // and then save
    saveBatch(employees);
    return SUCCESS;
  }

}
```

Is there a way when I can save data from form without processing of arrays,
but merely to save array of employees?
For instance:

```
<h4>Employee 1</h4>
<div>
<input type="text" name="employees.name">
<input type="text" name="employees.age">
<input type="text" name="employees.salary">
</div>

<h4>Employee 2</h4>
<div>
<input type="text" name="employees.name">
<input type="text" name="employees.age">
<input type="text" name="employees.salary">
</div>

<h4>Employee 3</h4>
<div>
<input type="text" name="employees.name">
<input type="text" name="employees.age">
<input type="text" name="employees.salary">
</div>
```

and action class:

```
public EmployeeAction extends ActionSupport {

  private Employee[] employees;

  // Setters and getters

  public String save() {
    saveBatch(employees);
    return SUCCESS;
  }

}
```

Comment: Of course you can do that. What is the problem?

Comment: Problem is that when I send data as
<input type="text" name="employees.name"> and so on...
employees array is null

Comment: Try with `List`. Do you have getters/setters for `Employee` fields?

Comment: @AleksandrM, earlier I tried to use List and this way didn't work. It's strange but now it work, as though I changed nothing :D Thanks a lot!